# How to launch .exe files from windows 10 (ubuntu) bash?

Tags: windows-10

I've installed sublime text from bash but it doesn't work it just return the bash prompt again .

then

I installed sublime natively on windows , problem is I can't run it from bash .

Comment: #edit , ` I quit windows` probably forever .

Answer (score 2):

It is already supported in Windows 10 latest build (build 14951), used like this:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32
$ notepad.exe
$ ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2
$ ls -la | findstr.exe foo.txt
$ cmd.exe /c dir
```

more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14951).

[There is a ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/333) about it in their Github page with some hacks you can use meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

It appears [at this time](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/733#issuecomment-237335958), the [cbwin](https://github.com/xilun/cbwin) project is our best bet. I just started running into these same issues with [trying to use vagrant from Bash on Windows](https://mikethecanuck.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/running-nix-apps-on-win10-anniversary-update-initial-findings/), and my vagrant install ran into issues that required kernel support (currently lacking in Bash on Windows).